# how to spread unbalanced data from long to wide in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 5 variables with 1000 rows. The first few rows and first  five columns are like:

```
id  trade   category    gender  experience
1   carpenter       c   m   no
1   mason           b   m   yes
2   electrician     a   f   no
2   plumber         a   f   no
2   carpenter       c   f   yes
2   mason           d   f   no
3   plumber         a   m   no
4   mason           b   m   yes
4   plumber             m   no
4   electrician     b   m   no
```

I tried spread and shape to convert from long to wide

I am expecting to see the as follows.

```
id  trade1     catgory1 trade2  category 2  trade3      category3   trade4  category4   gender
1   carpenter   c       mason   b            na             na        na    na  m
2   electrician a       plumber a            carpenter      c         mason d   f
3   plumber     a       na      na           na             na        na    na  m
4   mason       b       plumber na           electrician    b         na    na  m
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data in a usable way, using `dput()` and posting the result, or creating some fake data, and some attempts, code, clear desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` we can remove `experience` column since that is not needed in the final output, `gather` the dataframe in the long format,`group_by` `id` and `key` and create a new group identifier `key1` and `spread` it into wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%
  select(-experience) %>%
  gather(key, value ,-id, -gender) %>%
  group_by(id, key) %>%
  mutate(key1 = paste(key, row_number(), sep = "_"))  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  spread(key1, value)

df1

# A tibble: 4 x 10
#     id gender category_1 category_2 category_3 category_4 trade_1     trade_2 trade_3     trade_4
#  <int> <fct>  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>   <chr>       <chr>  
#1     1 m      c          b          NA         NA         carpenter   mason   NA          NA     
#2     2 f      a          a          c          d          electrician plumber carpenter   mason  
#3     3 m      a          NA         NA         NA         plumber     NA      NA          NA     
#4     4 m      b          b          b          NA         mason       plumber electrician NA
```

To arrange the columns in the required format we can do

```
df1 %>%
  select(id, gender, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"), ends_with("3"), ends_with("4"))
```

Or more generally,

```
cbind(df1[1:2], df1[-c(1:2)][order(readr::parse_number(names(df1[-(1:2)])))])
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
trade = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L
), .Label = c("carpenter", "electrician", "mason", "plumber"
), class = "factor"), category = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), 
experience = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak.  trade1 is associated with category1, trade2 is associated with category2 etc.  So, I want to see them next to each other. How can I do that?  thanks again